# Установка баннера

Tags: php

Привет!
Вот я написала внешний вид шутки которая здесь под названием Anmeldungsformular (http://bloomotion.com/affiliate_becomeaffiliate.php)

```
<table width="90%"><tbody>
<tr>
<td width="20%">HOMEPAGENAME:</td>
<td width="70%"><input size="40" name="seitenname" value="" maxlength="100" type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="20%">URL:</td><td width="70%">
<input size="40" name="adresse" value="http://" maxlength="200" type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="20%">BUTTON (88x31px):</td><td width="70%"><input name="button" type="file"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="20%">E-MAIL:</td><td width="70%"><input size="40" name="email" value="" type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="20%"></td>
<td width="70%"><input class="button" name="senden" value="ENTER" type="submit"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Результат:

```
<table width="90%"><tbody>
<tr>
<td width="20%">HOMEPAGENAME:</td>
<td width="70%"><input size="40" name="seitenname" value="" maxlength="100" type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="20%">URL:</td><td width="70%">
<input size="40" name="adresse" value="http://" maxlength="200" type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="20%">BUTTON (88x31px):</td><td width="70%"><input name="button" type="file"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="20%">E-MAIL:</td><td width="70%"><input size="40" name="email" value="" type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="20%"></td>
<td width="70%"><input class="button" name="senden" value="ENTER" type="submit"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Дело в том что она устанавливает автоматом баннеры без участия админа. Т.е. я зашла на эту ссылку, ввела все данные, которые требуются, и баннер тут же установился на страницу с аффилиатами.

Но у меня не получается сделать так, чтобы заполнив эту анкету
баннер смог автоматом оформиться на станице сайта

какой код нужно ввести чтоб все заработало?

Answer (score 1):

Сделать PHP скрипт, который внесет либо в базу то, что ввели либо в текст файл, если без базы сайт, чтобы потом из него показывать на страницах.

Comment: Эм а что за скрипт? Как его создать?

Comment: Посмотреть как у вас вывод делается банеров. Затем придумать, как вы будете хранить все данные от каждого, кто их вводит. После  чего выбрать язык сценариев серверных, которым владеете, и написать на нем скрипт сохранения/показа.

Comment: блин легко сказать
я ваще не понимаю как эти коды создавать
а есть какие нить готовые скрипты?
чтоб сразу скачать и установить
посоветуйте и если не сложно киньте ссыль где скачать)))

Comment: готовые есть к определенным сайтам. да и то врядли кто сделает специально такое идиотство чтобы ктото добавлял свое на сайт без админа. если хотите бан получить от поисковика потом за помойку то ищите. я таких скриптов не встречал... хотя его писать минут 10 в зависимости от того на какой сайт надо

Comment: ну у меня php и да мне нужна эт прога
и банов не будет он не такой популярный что он нем все знают)))